# Cannot retrieve email from Contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I want to retrieve email,phone number and contact names from my phone-book and display them in list-view.

The name and numbers are coming perfectly **but the emails are not retrieving.**

Here is the relevant code:

```
public  void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {
          String email="";
            Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
            //email = new String[phones.getCount()];

            while (phones.moveToNext())
            {
              String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
              String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
              String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
              System.out.println("name.................."+name+"........number......."+phoneNumber); 

              name1.add(name);
              phno1.add(phoneNumber);

             Cursor emailCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
             if(emailCur!=null)
             {
                 emailCur.moveToFirst();
             }
            // emailCur.moveToFirst();
              while (emailCur.moveToNext()) { 

                  email = emailCur.getString( emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                  System.out.println(email);
                  } 
                  email1.add(email); 
                  emailCur.close();


            }


            phones.close();

         }
```

I know this question has been asked previously but none of the solutions has worked for me.So can anybody point me out the mistake I am doing here??

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I solved it by changing kgandroid's code

```
String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
```

to

```
String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
```

(Note that ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID = "contact_id" while ContactsContract.Contacts._ID = "_id")

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        Cursor phones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+ " ASC");

        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
            HashMap<String,String> row = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
            System.out.println("name.................."+name+"........number......."+phoneNumber);

            row.put("Name",name);
            row.put("PhoneNo",phoneNumber);
            row.put("Email",getEmail(cr,id));
            contactList.add(row);
        }


        phones.close();
        return contactList;
    }

    private static String getEmail(ContentResolver cr,String contactId) {
        String emailStr = "";
        final String[] projection = new String[]{Email.DATA, Email.TYPE};

        final Cursor email = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI, projection, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{contactId}, null);

        if (email.moveToFirst()) {
            final int contactEmailColumnIndex = email.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA);

            while (!email.isAfterLast()) {
                emailStr = emailStr + email.getString(contactEmailColumnIndex) + ";";
                email.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        email.close();
        return emailStr;
    }

Note : add this <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/> in AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: Which "Data" I should import??? final Cursor email =  context.getContentResolver().query(Email.CONTENT_URI, projection, Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?"......Eclipse is giving me option to import 3 "data" classes.

Comment: try to import android.provider.ContactsContract.Data

Comment: retrieving only 1 contact

Comment: Still not working :/ ....   http://pastebin.com/vSWkyE9P ...here is the logcat...You can see only 1 email is retrieving.

Comment: is your all contact contain mail id ?

Comment: 4 of them contains mail id

Comment: sorry...cant get your last comment...!!

Comment: no there are no differences.I have added the rest of the emails in email section only in my device

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public  void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {
    String email="";
    // Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    //email = new String[phones.getCount()];

     while (phones.moveToNext()){
        String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        System.out.println("name.................."+name+"........number......."+phoneNumber); 

        name1.add(name);
        phno1.add(phoneNumber);

        Cursor emailCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null
        , ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?"
        , new String[]{id}, null);
        if(emailCur!=null){
            emailCur.moveToFirst();
        }

        // emailCur.moveToFirst();
        while (emailCur.moveToNext()) { 
            email = emailCur.getString( emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
            System.out.println(email);
        } 
        email1.add(email); 
        emailCur.close();
    }
    phones.close();
}
```

Comment: I have commented your Cursor initialization line and replaced it with mine.