# I am unable to get the EMAIL_ID column in my code instead it gets the contact number in the emailid column

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am posting my code here.
Please help me to get the email address of the contact.
Also I am getting a random list; please help me to sort the data as well.

```
package com.example.webwerks.retrievingcontactsdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  private String name;
  private String Number;
  private String alternateNumber;
  private String email_id;
  RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
  ListView listView;
  ArrayList <String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    getInformation(this.getContentResolver());
 //   relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutRelative);


}
public void getInformation(ContentResolver contentResolver){
    Cursor phones = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()){
        name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        Number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        email_id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
        arrayList.add(name);
        arrayList.add(Number);
        arrayList.add(email_id);
    }
    phones.close();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

This is my code.  It gives me the contact name and contact number(primary) and email id column.  Also, it shows me the contact number only.
And the data is not sorted according to my phone contact list.
Please help.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you have Email-ID set in Contacts ??

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25717989/cannot-retrieve-email-from-contacts/25718122#25718122

Comment: You need to execute another query too for all ids' ..check ma answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute another query using the `id` to get `Email` details of tat contact. SO check this code

## Better to go with DataModel class:

```
public class ContactData
{
    public String name;
    public String email;
}


ArrayList<ContactData> data = new ArrayList<>(); 
  public void getInformation(ContentResolver contentResolver){
            Cursor phones = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);


        while (phones.moveToNext()){
            String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            Cursor cur1 = contentResolver.query( 
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", 
                            new String[]{id}, null); 
            while (cur1.moveToNext()) { 
                //to get the contact names
                String name=cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                Log.e("Name :", name);
                String email = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                Log.e("Email", email);


                if(email!=null){
                    Toast.makeText(this,
                            "Name : "+ name+" EMail  : "+email, 1000)
                            .show();
                }
            } 
            dataList.add(contactData);
            cur1.close();


        }
        phones.close();




    }
```

Comment: I tried this code. I am getting the email address of the person when i debuged it. But that email address were not the one's corresponding to that contact :( if you can guide me proper as i m newbie

Comment: And also i am not getting the entire contact list. And the list is not sorted also

Comment: are you sure it's not corresponding ?? As I am gettong perfect..Go with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10117750/2591002) and tell me your output

Comment: Yes I Tried it but thats not giving me proper answer. Its gives me random email address for random contact.

Comment: follow [this](http://androidexample.com/Get_Contact_Emails_By_Content_Provider_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=121&aaid=141) buddy

Comment: I'm getting correct email for correct person..might be something is wrong with your code :(

Comment: Can you please put the edited code that i can just paste in my project. Because I have done all things the same but then too. As in Number also which is missing from the above code.

Comment: I have just toasted the email..so putting that code...then accordingly add it to Array as you need to show it in list.. Check ma code now

Comment: Yes It did Worked. It gave me email address number and name, But now the problem is in the list view the data is random eg: I got Name of some person email of some other person and number of some other person. The toast was giving me the exact result which i wanted but the listvew certainly doesnt do it for me

Comment: Then correctly add it to list Buddy :) Create a class having number name and email adderss and add the data the the arraylist of that class

Comment: Yes will try Thanks a lot for the help :)                           Can you just vote my question up such that it can add up in the reputation

Comment: I have edited the code to use Model class :) glad it helped you .. :)

Comment: Is this ArrayList in which class? The Mainactivity or the new class that is created?

Comment: whatever you want to do .... You can write it in Mainactivity  also or can create new class. Better to go with new class

Comment: But why does this code gives me limited contacts? I have some 500 Contacts on my device but it gives something around 70-80 contacts. Why it can be so?

Comment: Might be your 70-80 contacts only are having Email id

Comment: ohk So I Dont want like that. I needed all the contacts details which are there on my device.                                        example: if a contact has a name and number then it should be displayed in a list if one has number name and email then it should be done accordingly

Comment: then `dataList.add(contactData);` must be in outer loop... change your code  accordingly.First check the size of `cur1`

Comment: One more doubt I want edit and update the details from the application and the changes should also reflect in the original contact list on the device. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62220/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-chinmay-ghag).

Answer (score 0):

```
 cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
 cursor.moveToFirst();

 for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {

   contact = getContact(cursor, context.getContentResolver());
   cursor.moveToNext();
  }

  private Contact getContact(Cursor cur , ContentResolver cr){
    String contactID = cur.getString(cur
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
  if (contactID != null) 
 {

     // for reading all contact
        Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{contactID}, null);
        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {

            String contactNumber = pCur
                    .getString(pCur
                              .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            String contact_Number_Type = pCur
                    .getString(pCur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));

            contact.setContact_Number(contactNumber);
            contact.setContact_Number_Type(contact_Number_Type);

        }
        pCur.close();

        // for reading all email id

        Cursor emailCur = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{contactID}, null);
        while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {

            String emailContact = emailCur
                    .getString(emailCur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
            String emailType = emailCur
                    .getString(emailCur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));

            contact.setContact_Email(emailContact);
            contact.setContact_Email_Type(emailType);
        }

        emailCur.close();
}

}
```

Here Contact is a bean class

Comment: What Do you mean by bean class?

Comment: Class which is having some variables and for each variable there is getter setter method

Comment: You have to execute an another query for fetching the Email id

Comment: I did it also. But it gives me any random email fro any random contact i tried the code that was given by @SweetWisher. Below is the code for that. :(

Comment: Did you try the code that I have given you @chinmayghag

Comment: Give me sometime I will definitely try your code also and will comment on it :)