# Error when read Android contacts

Tags: android, contacts

I've gotten this snippet from StackOverflow:

```
Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    try{
        while (people.moveToNext()) {
            int nameFieldColumnIndex = people
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
            String contact = people.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);
            int numberFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            String number =  people.getString(numberFieldColumnIndex);

            System.out.println(contact + "-" + number);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    people.close();
```

When I try to read `phoneNum` column I get an error using `String number =  people.getString(numberFieldColumnIndex)`. Checking the column index I find that `numberFiledColomnIndex = -1`.

How can I get this snippet working?

Comment: Do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>` in your manifest?

Comment: inside `while (people.moveToNext()) {` add DatabaseUtils.dumpCurrentRow() in order to see the columns

Comment: Good question - but it sounds like the first getColumnIndex() (name field) is working.  This would imply the manifest permissions are probably OK.  IMHO...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25717989/cannot-retrieve-email-from-contacts

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html), getColumnIndex() returns -1 when the column doesn't exist.

Q: Are you passing the correct column name?  Is the spelling correct?

Comment: @user4769924 - Strong suggestion: step through the debugger.  Check the values of your actual database column fields; check the spelling of the value you're passing to getColumnIndex().  The entire problem could be a typo.