# Getting null while fetching email address of a Contact

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am working on an application that includes dealing with Contacts also. I have tried distinct methods But none of them worked.. I am fetching contact details in one of the tabbed Activity fragments. Its fetching all other details correctly except Email Address of the contact. I have figured out the reason because `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID` fetching different Ids than `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID`.. Now what should i code to fetch all the contacts from phone along with `name`, `number`, `email`, `photo_uri`. Please Help! Here is my piece of code:

```
    public class FragmentContacts extends Fragment{

ListView contacts;
ArrayList<String> namelist=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> number=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> contact_id=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> contact_image_uri=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> contact_email=new ArrayList<String>();
String[] sortImage;
ImageButton addContact;
String email;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);
    contacts=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.contact_list);
    addContact=(ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.add_contact);
    namelist.clear();
    getContacts();

    addContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addNewContact();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}


public void getContacts() {
    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();

    Cursor managedCursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI}, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC");

    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {

        String id = managedCursor.getString(0);
        String name = managedCursor.getString(1);
        String phoneNumber = managedCursor.getString(2);
        String image_uri=managedCursor.getString(3);
        //email=managedCursor.getString(4);
        email=getEmail(id);
        System.out.println("Email is "+email);
        contact_id.add(id);
       // System.out.println("Id is "+id+" "+"Name is "+name);
        namelist.add(name);
        number.add(phoneNumber);
        contact_image_uri.add(image_uri);
        contact_email.add(email);
    }
    managedCursor.close();



    ContactAdapter a = new ContactAdapter(getActivity(), contact_id, namelist, number,contact_image_uri,contact_email);
    contacts.setAdapter(a);
}


public void addNewContact()
{
    Intent in= new Intent(getContext(),AddContact.class);
    startActivity(in);
}

private String getEmail(String contactId) {

    String mailE=null;
    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
            new String[]{contactId}, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        mailE=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS));
        System.out.println("In Between Email is "+mailE);
    }

    cursor.close();
    return mailE;
}
 }
```

Comment: Did you try this SO link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117049/get-only-email-address-from-contact-list-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25717989/cannot-retrieve-email-from-contacts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get only email address from contact list Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117049/get-only-email-address-from-contact-list-android)

Comment: Try Cursor object as above answer link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i'v resolved it. I have changed `contact_id` from `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID` to `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID`... My Updated code is:

```
public class FragmentContacts extends Fragment{

ListView contacts;
ArrayList<String> namelist=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> number=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> contact_id=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> contact_image_uri=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> contact_email=new ArrayList<String>();
ImageButton addContact;
String email;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);
    contacts=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.contact_list);
    addContact=(ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.add_contact);
    namelist.clear();
    getContacts();

    addContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addNewContact();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}


public void getContacts() {
    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();

    Cursor managedCursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI}, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC");


    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {

        String id = managedCursor.getString(0);
        String name = managedCursor.getString(1);
        String phoneNumber=managedCursor.getString(2);
        String image_uri=managedCursor.getString(3);
        email=getEmail(id);
        contact_id.add(id);
        namelist.add(name);
        number.add(phoneNumber);
        contact_image_uri.add(image_uri);
        contact_email.add(email);
    }
    managedCursor.close();

    ContactAdapter a = new ContactAdapter(getActivity(), contact_id, namelist, number,contact_image_uri,contact_email);
    contacts.setAdapter(a);
}


public void addNewContact()
{
    Intent in= new Intent(getContext(),AddContact.class);
    startActivity(in);
}

private String getEmail(String contactId) {

    String mailE=null;
    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
            new String[]{contactId}, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        mailE=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS));
    }

    cursor.close();
    return mailE;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Getting Email Address Email,

```
 String email = managedCursor .getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can you this method to get the email ID of that contact. In your case you can pass the contact ID directly.

```
public ArrayList<String> getEmail() {
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                Cursor cur1 = cr.query( 
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", 
                                new String[]{id}, null); 
                while (cur1.moveToNext()) { 
                    //to get the contact names
                    String name=cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    Log.e("Name :", name);
                    String email = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    Log.e("Email", email);
                    if(email!=null){
                        names.add(name);
                    }
                } 
                cur1.close();
            }
        }
        return names;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's some confusion in your code, you can't query over `Phone.CONTENT_URI` and expect to get an email-address, as emails are stored in `Email.CONTENT_URI`.

The naive way would be to add another query over `Email.CONTENT_URI`, but that's not needed, your best choice would be to query over the entire `Data.CONTENT_URI` table which contains both emails and phones (and a lot of other types of information), and ask for only mimetypes for emails and phones.

```
String[] projection = new String[] { Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME, Data.MIMETYPE, Email.ADDRESS, Phone.NUMBER };
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, Data.MIMETYPE + " IN ('" + Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' , '" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE +"')", null, null);

while ((cur != null) && cur.moveToNext()) {
    long contactId = cur.getLong(0);
    String name = cur.getString(1);
    String type = cur.getString(2);
    String email = null;
    String phone = null;
    if (type == Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE) {
      email = cur.getString(3);
    } else {
      phone = cur.getString(4);
    }
    // do whatever you want with above variables.
}
```

**Note:** you'll get the same `contactId` and `name` for each phone/email stored for that contact, so you should use a `HashMap` to map contactId to list of details, in order to store all this data.

You should definitely read first to docs about the [ContactsContract](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) API, and [Contacts](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html) and [Data](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) tables, as these are crucial to understanding how to query for information about contacts.